# Return only members from Google group

Tags: python, google-api

I've been retrieving members of Google groups successfully for some time now using this Python code:

```
for group in groups_list:
        members = service.members()
        member_request = members.list(groupKey=group['email'], maxResults=200, roles='MEMBER')     
        memberEmails = []

        while member_request is not None:
            member_results = member_request.execute()
            member_list = member_results.get('members', [])
            for member in member_list:
                memberEmails.append(member['email'].lower())

            member_request = members.list_next(member_request, member_results)
```

I noticed a couple of weeks ago that this is returning all group members regardless of their role.  I can't figure out if Google changed the API or if I have always been returning all members regardless of role. Either way, I need only to return users with the role of MEMBER and **not** MANAGER or OWNER. Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you share what the google groups looks like as a dataset? Before it hits your for loop

Comment: I assume your asking for the code block before this? `groups = service.groups()
request = groups.list(customer='my_customer', maxResults=200, query='name=\''+emailGroupName+'\'')
groups_results = request.execute()
groups_list = groups_results.get('groups', [])`

Comment: According to https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-group-members, the data is as follows:
{
   "kind": "directory#members",
   "members": [
   {
    "kind": "directory#member",
    "id": "group member's unique ID",
    "email": "liz@example.com",
    "role": "MANAGER",
    "type": "GROUP"
   },
   {
    "kind": "directory#member",
    "id": "group member's unique ID",
    "email": "radhe@example.com",
    "role": "MANAGER",
    "type": "MEMBER"
   }
  ],
   "nextPageToken": "NNNNN"
}

Comment: If this is the api you are using, I would recommend accessing data differently - parse it into a dictionary, then you can either convert it to a pd dataframe or loop through entries in dict["members"]

list = []
for mem in dict["members"]:
     if mem["role"] == "member":
       list.append(mem["email"]

If this is not the api you are using, can you direct us to the api so we can look at the data as it comes in from your query?